# library on pythonpath not accessible

Tags: python, package, pythonpath

I have a library that is on the pythonpath:

```
In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.path
Out[3]:                                                                                                                                                                                               
['',                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 ...                                                                                                                                                                
 '/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library', 
]
```

It is registered in ~/.profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library"
```

yet when I enter python/Ipython, I can't see it or use it. It has **init**.py in its highest level. I use kubuntu and suddenly it doesn't work, but anything I pip install does. What can cause this? Thank you

Comment: The file needs to be called `__init__.py`

Comment: it is, that is something stack overflow does

Comment: it was working on a different laptop with the same export statement and the same folder in the same path

Comment: is `my_scripting_library` the package directory or its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folders on the PYTHONPATH should contain folders that are python packages, and not be the paths to the packages themselves.

In this case, if my_scripting_library is your package, and '/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library' contains the __init__.py file, it will not be valid.

Assuming my_scripting_library is the package you wish to import, ensure the __init__.py file is within '/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library', then the folder on the path should be:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/cchilders/scripts/python"
```

You can then in Python do this:

```
>>> import my_scripting_library
```

Comment: why is that? why would you use the parent and not the actual directory, that seems nonsensical to me

Comment: As you scale up to potentially hundreds of libraries having to path each individually would get extremely problematic. By the same reasoning, it allows you to drop new libraries in quickly by dropping them into an already existing folder on the path.

Comment: If it helps, think of the path as places to look for things. It follows the same behaviour as the OS, but instead of the things being executables in the OS, the things are libraries in Python. The OS searches all folders on the path for the executable that matches when you type a command, and if you had to path each binary individually think how messy your path would get!